# Using Postbacks with a CDN

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate, cdn

We have a Sitecore/Webforms based website that we'd like to run behind Akamai  CDN however we're having an issue with ViewState MAC validation on our postbacks.

We've worked around this for most of the core forms on the site (by taking them out of the CDN cache and serving them direct for every user), but we're left with a simple form in the footer of every page that posts back to the server.

Currently we're seeing errors:

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed.
```

I believe this is caused by the CDN caching the viewstate fields from the original request and these (obviously) not matching for other users.

As we are running this site on multiple servers, we already have the `machinekey` correctly configured (we've been able to use postBackUrl settings to post back to other pages/SSL instances/etc.) before we added Akamai.

As we're running Asp.NET 4.5.2 there's no way we can even attempt to disable viewstate MAC even if we thought it was a good idea.

Setting `ViewStateMode=Disabled` still leaves us with a tiny viewstate (presumably the MAC) which still causes problems.

Is there anyway we can remove the session dependence from the viewstate?

The basic steps we can use to replicate this:

1. Request page from Browser A - Akamai caches page.
2. Submit form from Browser A - Success!
3. Request page from Browser B - Akamai serves cached page.
4. Submit form from Browser B - ERROR!

Comment: Typically CDN's only host the _static_ content for a site: things like images, js, css, web fonts, pdf downloads, etc. Your core site should still be on your own servers, not on a CDN. If you want a distributed site, it's time for a cloud provider like Azure or AWS.

Comment: Yes - I guess the issue is that the main pages feel like a static site (in that all users will see the same content, etc.) however the viewstate makes it dynamic.

Comment: If it's truly static, you don't need ASP.Net at all... you can just html. If the user has the ability to request specific content into a page... even if any user can request any of the content... then it's dynamic and doesn't belong in the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, Akamai CDN never caches POST requests. But its good idea to try adding the forms to do not cache list and try replicate the issue.