# Asp.Net ViewState behind CDN

Tags: asp.net, caching, cdn, varnish, viewstate

I have an Asp.Net app running under IIS with two backend servers with Loadbalancing + machinekey configured. Once I've activated a CDN (Varnish with caching disabled), I'm redirected to login page every time I navigate between pages.

I believe that the postbacks are cached somewhere and the app logs don't help.
I've seen similar answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922193/using-postbacks-with-a-cdn), but none of them suggested a solution.

Any idea how to track this down without changing the App config?

On the browser, this is what I see :

- https://example.com/
- 302 redirection to https://example.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f
- successful login redirects to https://example.com/accueil.aspx  with some errors (see attached)
- selcting https://example.com/pages/module.aspx?PAGEID=-00000001  reurn a 302 redirection  to loginn page https://example.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fpages%2faccueil.aspx%3fMSG%3dIdentification+obligatoire
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHCDv.jpg)

Comment: Where is attaachement?